# How to set width in Card and Deck macro?

Tags: confluence

I use card/deck macro, and I have a problem with setting width of column. For example I have this code:

```
{card}
||Test|data|
||Result|data|
{card}
```

if I use this macro in this way the left column have width by the longest word in it, but if I break rows like this (it's needed for logical divide attributes in left column):

```
{card}
||Test|data|

||Result|data|
{card}
```

This looks like two blocks with different column width.

I think there be an attribute in card something like width or else, but i don't know exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is add CSS in wiki markup between the `{html}{html}` tags.
There are two classes in confluence table .confluenceTh and .confluenceTd, for header and cell. It looks like:

```
{html}
<style type="text/css">

.confluenceTh{
 width:300px;

}
.confluenceTd{
 width:300px;

}
</style>
{html}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to control the column size of the table using `[{table-plus}][1]` which has a `width` option.

```
{card:label=mycard}    
{table-plus:columnAttributes=style=width:300px, style=width:300px}
||Head1|D1|

||Head2|D2|
{table-plus}
{card}
```